# Finding the value of $f(2001)$ given the functional equation $f\bigl(f(n)\bigr)= 3n$ and strict monotonicity of $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math, functional-equations

> Let $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ be a strictly increasing function such that $f\bigl(f(n)\bigr)= 3n\ \forall\ n\in \mathbb N$
> Find the value of $f(2001).$

Now I tried to solve this by myself but I'm stuck somewhere in the middle of my solution. Please help me with my solution. Also my solution is a bit long as I'm writing almost every observation I made, so please be kind enough to bear with me.

***My Approach:***

We know that $f$ is strictly increasing.

Suppose for some $n_1$ and $n_2$, we have $f(n_1)=f(n_2)$. Thus $f\bigl(f(n_1)\bigr)=f\bigl(f(n_2)\bigr)\implies 3n_1=3n_2$ hence $n_1=n_2$.
 (I just realized that his step was actually not required.)

$\therefore$ $f$ is an injective strictly increasing function.

Suppose for some $n\in \mathbb N$, we have $f(n)\leq n$, then $f\bigl(f(n))\leq f(n)\leq n$ as $f$ is strictly increasing.

This gives us $3n\leq n$ which isn't true for any $n\in \mathbb N$.

$\therefore f(n)>n\ \forall\ n\in \mathbb N $

Now suppose $f(1)=l>1$. Thus $f\bigl(f(1)\bigr)=3=f(l)>f(1)=l\implies 1<l<3$ and since $l\in \mathbb N$, we know that $f(1)=2$.

This means that $f\bigl(f(1)\bigr)=f(2)=3$ and $f\bigl(f(2)\bigr)=f(3)=6$ and so on.

A few such values are:

$f(1)=2$
$f(2)=3$
$f(3)=6$
$f(6)=9$
$f(9)=18$
$f(18)=27$
$f(27)=54$
$f(54)=81$

Now here a pattern can be observed.

**Claim:** $f(3^n)=2\cdot3^n$

**Proof:** Suppose the above claim is true. Then $f\bigl(f(3^n)\bigr)=f(2\cdot3^n)=3^{n+1}$. Now $f\left(3^{n+1}\right)=f\bigl(f(2\cdot3^n)\bigr)=2\cdot3^n\cdot3=2\cdot3^{n+1}$

$\therefore$ $f(3^n)=2\cdot3^n$ and $f(2\cdot3^n)=3^{n+1}$

One more thing can be observed here that if $3^n<k<2\cdot3^n$, then $2\cdot3^n<f(k)<3^{n+1}$ and since there are exactly $3^n$ permitted values for both $k$ and $f(k)$ and $f$ is strictly increasing, the unique function satisfying the given condition can easily be found.

But unfortunately $2\cdot3^6<2001<3^7$, thus a unique function cannot be found using the observation stated above.

Now this is where I am stuck. Firstly, is this question solvable using my approach? If yes, then what should I add to my approach in order to reach the solution? Please help.

***THANKS***

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but since $f$ is strictly increasing and we have $f(3)=6, f(6)=9$, we must have $f(4)=7, f(5)=8$. This method could be extended.

Comment: Not sure, also., if it helps, but $f(f(n))=3n \Rightarrow f(3n)=f(f(f(n)))=3f(n)$, so
$f(2001)=f(3\cdot 667)=3f(667)$

Comment: @player3236, Exactly! This was one of the observation and this is the observation which led me to the conclusion mentioned in $3^n<k<2\cdot3^n$ case. But unfortunately this doesn't work on $2001$.

Comment: IIRC, this an older contest task from the BAMO (Bay Area Mathematical Olympiad), and the most elegant solution available looks at it with "Ternary numeral system eyes".

Comment: This question should not be closed as a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027239/let-f-mathbb-n-rightarrow-mathbb-n-are-increasing-function-such-that-f-le). If anything, the version here has much more context to support it, so the other question should be closed as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[$f(f(7))=21$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_VII), but we have $f(12)=21$ from the "exactly $3^n$ permitted values" point, so $f(7)=12$. In the same way we can show $f(8)=15,f(19)=30$ and so on. In general
$$f(3^n)=2\cdot3^n$$
$$f(2\cdot3^n)=3\cdot3^n$$
$$f(3^n+k)=2\cdot3^n+k,0\le k\le3^n$$
$$f(2\cdot3^n+k)=3\cdot3^n+\mathbf{3k},\ 0\le k\le 3^n$$
Thus
$$f(2001)=f(2\cdot3^6+543)=3\cdot3^6+3\cdot543=3816$$
$f$ is [OEIS A003605](https://oeis.org/A003605). The same question but asking for $f(1992)$ was problem 5 of BMO 1992.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I didn't understand how you got $f(2\cdot3^n+k)$. Will you please explain it once more? I am again sorry for not getting it.

Comment: $f(2\cdot 3^k+k) = f(f(3^n+k)) = 3\cdot (3^n+k)=3^{n+1}+3k$

Comment: @DevanshKamra Your "exactly $3^n$ permitted values" point gives a formula for $f(3^n+k)$, whose result is a number in $[2\cdot3^n,3\cdot3^n]$. Yet $f(f(2\cdot3^{n-1}+k))=2\cdot3^n+3k$ lies in the same range, and the strict monotonicity of $f$ allows us to conclude the formula for $f(2\cdot3^n+k)$.